# Writing a lot of values to a file with the same format and line breaks

Tags: fortran

I want to write multiple values to a file, all of the same type (float). This is generally pretty easy to write as I can put '20(f10.3,1x)' as the format to write all the values. The problem here is that I want line breaks in between certain values. An example of what I want to achieve is:

```
write(output_unit,*format goes here*) a1, a2, *line break*, a3, a4,&
      & a5, *line break*, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, *line break*, a12,&
      & a13, *line break*, ...
```

All the variables here are of the same format, but the line breaks appear at different locations. Note that 'a' here is not an array. They are all separate variables.

Is there a way to add line breaks either in the format section without having to repeat the `'(f10.3,1x)'` 20 times?

I know I can define the format separately as

```
10 format(f10.3,1x)
```

but can I use something like

```
write(output_unit,2(10),'/',3(10),'/',...)
```

Comment: Why not try it and see for yourself?

Comment: If I try it the way I suggested in the question, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Do you know about the G edit descriptor and the `new_line` function? But those add up to a hack: why do you want to do this with one format with interspersed new lines, instead of separating the output in to the logical record structure which it naturally appears to be?

Comment: That is, what is wrong with `write(unit, fmt) a1, a2; write(unit, fmt) a3, a4, a5; ...` with `fmt` as the natural format?

Comment: @francescalus Isn't G descriptor just a floating point format? How will that allow me to use line breaks?
The new_line function requires a character format right? I'll have to include that separately between multiple floating point formats.

I could do separate write functions. I was just wondering if there is a way to include all of that in one line.

Thank you.

Comment: No G is not a floating point edit descriptor. It's not even a numeric one: G is for "generalized".

Comment: It is arguably much clearer to use multiple output statements. You want to separate the output of items into arbitrary grouping and the clear way to express the arbitrary grouping is through distinct output statements rather than burying a record delimiter at obscure points in the output list. (If you have a consistent structure of, say, five items upon a line, it's clear to use a single output statement,  the distinction here is with non-structured output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to build up a single input/output format using expressions of labelled format statements (as you are trying with `2(10),'/',3(10),'/',...`).  It *is* possible to build up one with character expressions, but, gosh, wouldn't that be horrible?

Instead, you can intersperse the slash edit descriptor in a more explicitly written way using the same repeat count specifier:

```
print '(2(f10.3,1x),/,3(f10.3,1x))', a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
```

That is, you write out the fundamental unit (`(f10.3,1x)`) each time, rather than referencing a labelled format statement.

This is less ugly than a large character expression, but ugly it remains. Your structure is much more clearly shown using multiple output statements:

```
character(*), parameter :: fmt='(*(f10.3,1x))'

print fmt, a1, a2
print fmt, a3, a4, a5
```

Yes, one can also use generalized editing (`Gw.d`) with a new line in the output list, but that also obfuscates the structure of your output (and note also that there's no `Gw.d` that behaves exactly like `f10.3`).

Answer (score 1):

A combination of g edit descriptor and new_line:

```
program test
   character, parameter :: NL = new_line( 'A' )
   write( *, "( *(1x, g5.0) )" ) 1, 2, NL, 3, 4, 5, NL, 6, 7, 8, 9
end program test
```

Output:

```
 1     2     
 3     4     5     
 6     7     8     9
```

If you want reals ("floats") then you might need greater potential length:

```
program test
   character, parameter :: NL = new_line( 'A' )
   write( *, "( *(1x, g9.2) )" ) 1.0, 2.0, NL, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, NL, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0
end program test
```

Output:

```
   1.0       2.0             
   3.0       4.0       5.0             
   6.0       7.0       8.0       9.0
```